# Adding stray hairs to hair particles?

Tags: rendering, particles, eevee-render-engine, hair

i'm not too sure if i worded it right, but i'm looking for a way to make hair look more spares in some areas so it has some stray fly away hairs

[image]

[image]

the first image is the look i'm going for, while the second is my current project file and what i've achieved so far. i've tried fiddling around with a few settings but i can't seem to find the right one just yet.

is there anyway to easily achieve this, or would they need to be added and styled by hand?

[2.8 blend hair file on google drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iRX0vwCN1IYTqzVfF-vp9LZSNhTFx8Ey)

Answer (score 1):

so, i found out the best way to do it. increase the roughness, but also increase the threshold as well. the roughness makes it more shaggy so it's not combed to a point, but the threshold makes sure that there are some combed hairs as ll